# Behaviour of Table context menu in Vaadin 7.3 unclear

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a simple use case: in a multi select `Table`

- when the user selects 1 row, a context menu with two actions must be returned (DELETE and DOWNLOAD)
- when the user selects more than one row, only the DELETE Action should be in the context menu

This is the code I use:

```
    contactList.setMultiSelect(true);        
    final Action delete = new Action("Delete", FontAwesome.TIMES);
    final Action download = new Action("Download", FontAwesome.DOWNLOAD);
    contactList.addActionHandler(new Action.Handler() {

        @Override
        public Action[] getActions(Object target, Object sender) {
            final Table table = (Table)sender;
            // if Table is in multi select mode, getValues() returns Set of item id's
            if (table.isMultiSelect() && ((Set)table.getValue()).size() > 1) {
                return new Action[] {delete};
            } else {
                return new Action[] {delete, download};
            }
        }

        ...
```

I see that `getActions()` is called by the `Table` component every time a row selection is made. It returns the correct `Action` array. However, in the UI, only one context menu is used, independent of the actions returned.
This topic is not covered in *The Book of Vaadin*. There is an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514223/) but the solutions is way too complicated and the solution suggested by Joonas is not working (in fact the case i describe here).

Comment: Can you check that contactList.setImmediate(true) is actually set?

Comment: Yes, setImmediate is set to true (I am using the AddressbookUI sample for trying out features)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a well-known issue in Vaadin from version 6. Most people (including me) work-around this by using [ContextMenu Addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/69)